# Clojure Mandatory keyword argument

Tags: clojure, keyword-argument

I have a function like this:

```
(defn foo [{a :keya b :keyb}]
  (list a b))
```

And i'm calling it like this:

```
(foo {:keya "hi"}) ; Returns ("hi" nil)
```

If I don't give `keyb` keyword argument, it takes nil for that. Is there a way to ensure that it throws exception for it instead of taking it as nil.

( I know that I can manually check and throw an exception, but is there any special option which enforces the constraints.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a precondition (http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc9) to assert the key is present:

```
(defn foo [{a :keya b :keyb}] 
   {:pre [(not (nil? b))]}
   (list a b))
```

This will throw an AssertionError when the key is nil.

Answer (score 2):

No, but of course because Clojure is a lisp you can define your own macro that handles the boring "manual checking" for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

[aldazosa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382720/clojure-mandatory-keyword-argument#17383027) gave you the right solution, but `{:keya nil :keyb nil}` is the valid map too. To allow `nil` values you may use `contains?` instead of `nil?` check:

```
(defn foo [{a :keya b :keyb :as m}]
  {:pre [(every? (partial contains? m)
                 [:keya :keyb])]}
  (list a b))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more complex look at [Validateur](http://clojurevalidations.info/) or [bouncer](https://github.com/leonardoborges/bouncer)